# Updating data with $set and $sum mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I was trying to do update and sum up the column value.

```
await single_sku_db.collection("test").updateOne(
      { _id: ObjectId(id) },
      {
        $push: {
          report: {
            $each: [
              {
                name: name,
                views,
              },
            ],
            $position: 0,
          },
        },
        $set: {
          report_status: "Completed",
          total_views: { $sum: "$report.views"},
        },
      }
```

I cant sum the report.views like this, will get this error.

> the dollar ($) prefixed field ‘’ is not valid for storage.

Is there anyway to do this without using aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to replace the `$set` with `$inc` for this:

```
await single_sku_db.collection("test").updateOne(
      { _id: ObjectId(id) },
      {
        $push: {
          report: {
            $each: [
              {
                name: name,
                views,
              },
            ],
            $position: 0,
          },
        },
        $set: {report_status: "Completed"},
        $inc: {total_views: views},
      })
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PPNHo56KE2S)